# changing the behavoiur of the box depending upon style property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my jquery i am creating boxes and everything is working expected:

I am trying to detct if the `style` property is `text-align:right;` , it should show the username at the end and message to be at the first like the below code: i shows by default name and message on the left

```
style='text-align:right;';

$("#mybox_" + boxtitle + " .boxcontent")
    .append('<div class="boxmessage" style="' + style + '">
                 <span class="boxmessagefrom">' + sender + ':&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                 <span class="boxmessagecontent">' + item.m + '</span>
             </div>');
```

so i am tring like this

```
if(style contains 'right') {
 $("#mybox_" + boxtitle + " .boxcontent")
     .append('<div class="boxmessage" style="' + style + '">
                  <span class="boxmessagecontent">' + item.m + '</span>
                  <span class="boxmessagefrom">' + sender + ':&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
              </div>');
}
```

Comment: if($(element).css('text-align') == 'right')) you can use this.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something with javascript that would be better handled with well structured HTML and CSS. Maybe it would be better if you provided an example of the output layout you are trying to achieve.